# All of the about_* topics are missing from my PowerShell help. What gives?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, help-files, powershell-5.0

I've not used PowerShell often on this machine — it was updated from windows 7 pro to windows 10 a few months ago. $PSVersionTable shows I'm on version 5.

I've run update-help as administrator, but all of the about_ help topics are missing, EXCEPT for about_CimSession for some reason. That is, when I run `Get-Help * | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like "about_*" }`, I get about_CimSession as the only result. Any attempts to get other about_ topics result in a search list or a related topic.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Older powershell versions seemed to install WITH help files, the newer versions seem to NOT include those files. They only come down after you've invoked `update-help`. If you're behind a proxy, make sure it is assigned, otherwise `update-help` will fail.

Comment: @Craig620 I've been running `update-help -force` till the cows come home, but it's not getting me any new `about_` topics. It's like PS5 doesn't know they are supposed to exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `Update-Help -Force` as local administrator as you have done already to make sure that the help files are present in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US` or your locale.

**Then verify that the *file extensions* for the `about_` help files are actually `.help.txt` and not just `.txt`** PowerShell help files need to be `.help.txt`.

There is an issue somewhere in the `Update-Help` process in PowerShell v5 where the files are being named `.txt`.

The following one-liner will `Move-Item` (**not** `Rename-Item` more on that below) all the `.txt` into `.help.txt`. This path will include Module help files also in the usual PowerShell system directory — make sure to check if your PowerShell is installed somewhere else.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0' -Recurse -Include '*.txt' -Exclude '*.help.txt' | Move-Item -Destination { $_.DirectoryName + '\' + $_.Name -replace '.txt$','.help.txt' } -Force
```

After renaming the `.txt` to `.help.txt` your `Get-Help about*` will work again.

However, if you run `Update-Help -Force` a new set of ***incorrect*** `.txt` will be downloaded again. Hence the reason for the script above using `Move-Item` (instead of `Rename-Item`) as you can run it again for cleanup multiple times.

This issue needs to be sorted out by Microsoft.

Comment: This is amazing, and was a contributing factor to the issue I was experiencing, so, points! Turns out there were also a couple of modules with the same file name issue. Additionally, some helpfiles were just flat out missing, and there now exists a solution for that: https://github.com/kilasuit/Install-AboutHelp

Comment: Oh oops. The one-liner you provided moves all of those files to C:\ Working on a fix...

Comment: One more thing. The latest set of help files that get downloaded with the wrong extension appear to have terrible formatting compared with their 2014-era counterparts—check out about_Execution_Policies if you can. What a mess!

Comment: Odd that for you the files weren't being moved correctly. Good updates to the answer/post. Thank you. Ridiculous that Microsoft hasn't fixed yet as of November 2016.

Answer (score 1):

It was stupid locale for me. `Get-UICulture` returns `en-GB`, but apparently help is only available in `en-US`, because of course it is.

```
Update-Help -Force -UICulture en-US -Verbose
```

Works fine on 7.2.4 on Ubuntu ARMx64.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It solves the issue of missing about_* help files on Win 8.1 with non-US UICulture. Works for both 5.1 and 7.2.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem with not being able to get-help with any about_ topics on my Win10 machine. All the help files were there with the .help.txt extensions. I also had VMware PowerCLI installed. I renamed the Modules folder for PowerCLI at C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Modules and everything worked okay. I ended up uninstalling PowerCLI.